# How to define a class within another class in CLIPS?

Tags: oop, clips

Suppose, I have a defined class **Coin** in CLIPS and also I have a class **Board**

```
(defclass Coin 
          (is-a USER)
          (role concrete)
   (slot Side (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols Head Tail))
)
```

How to properly defined a class **Board** with three coins on it? Something like this:

```
(defclass Board
          (is-a USER)
          (role concrete)
   (slot CoinOne (type Coin))
   (slot CoinTwo (type Coin))
   (slot CoinThree (type Coin))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can automatically populate instances of one class within another class:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(defclass Coin 
   (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot Side (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols Head Tail)))
CLIPS> 
(defclass Board
   (is-a USER)
   (role concrete)
   (slot CoinOne 
      (type INSTANCE)
      (allowed-classes Coin)
      (default-dynamic (make-instance of Coin)))
   (slot CoinTwo
      (type INSTANCE)
      (allowed-classes Coin)
      (default-dynamic (make-instance of Coin)))
   (slot CoinThree
      (type INSTANCE)
      (allowed-classes Coin)
      (default-dynamic (make-instance of Coin))))
CLIPS> (make-instance [b1] of Board)
[b1]
CLIPS> (instances)
[initial-object] of INITIAL-OBJECT
[b1] of Board
[gen1] of Coin
[gen2] of Coin
[gen3] of Coin
For a total of 5 instances.
CLIPS> (send [b1] print)
[b1] of Board
(CoinOne [gen1])
(CoinTwo [gen2])
(CoinThree [gen3])
CLIPS> (send [gen1] print)
[gen1] of Coin
(Side Head)
CLIPS>
```